# Custom control reference not working on different machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, reference, web-config

I have a simple asp.NET webforms project that has a single custom control (a datepicker) that I downloaded the .dll from another site.  To use it, I just downloaded the dll, right clicked my project in VS2010 and "Add reference", then at the top of the page, used the following code:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="DatePickerControl" Namespace="DatePickerControl" tagprefix="cc1" %>
```

Everything works fine on my own machine.  But after someone had copied my project folder and put it own there own harddrive, they open the project to find errors of the reference not being found.  It's in the BIN folder on both of our machines and I have the properties of the assembly set to "Copy Local".

Not really sure how to search for the solution to this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On your colleague's machine, don't change the code, just remove the reference and re-add it.

Comment: Well.  Long story, but it was something My colleague was doing wrong.  lol  All is good now, thank you for your help.

I'm new here, am I supposed to vote your reply as the solution?  It could have been.

Comment: If you feel that I provided your answer then please mark it as the answer.